# Modulus operator nim

Tags: modulus, nim-lang

What is the modulus operator in Nim?

`tile % 9 == 0` results in undeclared identifier: '%'

Googling or searching SO doesn't bring up an answer.

Comment: [manual](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html), Ctrl-F, modulo: "`a %% b`: unsigned integer modulo operation" :) There's also a `mod` operator (see under Operators).

Comment: Ahhh thank you! I was looking at these operators https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#lexical-analysis-operators which appeared `%` was valid. Looking closer now I see the is also `mod`

Comment: @paxdiablo I think Google was stemming `modulus` to `modulo` and returning the manual page, but in my impatience I couldn't find modulus on the page and I left without looking for modulo.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Others have suggested using `%%`, but don't do that. It is a remnant of a time when Nim used to have only signed integers. The operators ending with `%` like `<%` are used to handle these signed integers as unsigned ints. Since Nim has had unsigned integers for a while now, simply use the `mod` operator that is correctly overloaded for all relevant integral types: https://nim-lang.org/docs/system.html#mod,int,int

Answer (score 9):

You can use the modulus operator with the `mod` keyword like this:

```
tile mod 9 == 0
```